# What about "ZGDI" object or class, what file sould I include in my source code?

Tags: c, visual-studio, header, visual-c++-6

I 'd encounter one problem that my source code has this "ZGDI" define in a struct.

But my Visual Studio 6.0 enviroment did't find it's definition.

By what method could I that this "ZGDI" to be seen , or I should have

include some what *.h file???

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard type. Why is it in your source code? That should lead you to the answer. Presumably, you're trying to use some library, include its headers.